# Slide Show Fade Effect is Jerking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My image slider works, except the first time the images rotate, one image jerks. On the following passes it is smooth?

Javascript Code.

```
var imgArray = [
   'about.jpg',
   'about2.jpg',
   'about3.jpg'],
   curIndex = 0;
   imgDuration = 5000;

function slideShow() {
   document.getElementById('slider').className += "fadeOut";
   setTimeout(function() {
       document.getElementById('slider').src = imgArray[curIndex];
       document.getElementById('slider').className = "";
   },1000);
   curIndex++;
   if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
      setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
}
slideShow();
```

CSS Code.

```
#slider {
   opacity:1;
   transition: opacity 1s;
   float:left;
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
   margin-right:20px;
   border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px;
   border-color:#CCC;
   border-style:ridge;
   border-width:2px; 
}

#slider.fadeOut {
   opacity:0;
}
```

My Site.
[See the effect on my site](http://everythirdday.net)

This is the only html involved.

```
img id="slider" src="images/other-images/blank.jpg"
```

You can view the site with your code in place at.
[Test Site](http://3.kenerly.com)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the image loading.

You could create a jquery plugin like below:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

$(['about.jpg','about2.jpg','about3.jpg']).preload();
```

So your code will end up being like this:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

var imgArray = [
'about.jpg',
'about2.jpg',
'about3.jpg'],
curIndex = 0;
imgDuration = 5000;

imgArray.preload();

function slideShow() {
    document.getElementById('slider').className += "fadeOut";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('slider').src = imgArray[curIndex];
        document.getElementById('slider').className = "";
    },1000);
    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
    setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
}
slideShow();
```

Iv'e not tested but this shows you that you need to preload the images first.

One library I like to use is Owl Carousel which is really easy to setup & use https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

**EDIT**
Just make sure you are referencing the images correctly in:

```
var imgArray = [
'about.jpg',
'about2.jpg',
'about3.jpg']
```

so this could be:

```
var imgArray = [
'/path/to/about.jpg',
'/path/to/about2.jpg',
'/path/to/about3.jpg']
```

Comment: Chris using your code, no images show. I failed to post the html for this, not sure if it changes anything?

Comment: <img id="slider" src="images/other-images/blank.jpg">

Comment: Triple checked file location, also using the current code (the one I posted) the images show up. Used same path for your code, but no images. I do appreciate all the help...

Comment: can you update your question with your HTML and i will have a look?

Comment: Updated and added test site url